# Near/Spatial Join picking wrong polyline segment as closest?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, line, spatial-join

I have a set of points near a street centerline. I need to find the perpendicular point on the street centerline, and use their x y instead of the GPS information of the original points.

I tried Near tool and spatial join in Arcgis 10.1. They returned the same result of a segment which is far away from the right one. For example, for point (60.0001, 40.0001), I could see from the street centerline attribute table that there's a segment start from (60.0002, 40.0002). Yet the Near tool and Spatial Join tool return the same wrong result, which  a segment start from(60.002, 40.002) This could be a neighborhood away.

Anyone has any idea? Any other intuitive tools I could use?

Comment: My guess is that there's a coordinate reference system problem. The example you gave looks like the projected CRS default tolerance (1 mm / 0.001 m) but the values look like lat/lon using a geographic CRS. A geographic CRS will use a tolerance around 10e-07 degrees instead.

Comment: Are you able to include a diagram to try and make what you are asking clearer, please?  At the moment I would need to be making too many guesses if I were to try and reproduce what you are describing in order to explain what you are observing.

Comment: Thank you guys!@mkennedy you are right! I later figured it out. So always make sure the shapefile has right coordinate system! (When I created my shapefile from a table, the default coordinate system is the same as my data frame, instead of the table itself.) Many thanks!